# Is Div-resizing and/or adding linebreaks in the WP7 browser missing?

Tags: internet-explorer

I just bought a WP7 phone and there is one thing that bothers me.

On Android or iOS when I read a webpage (without a mobile view) and I zoom in to make the letters bigger they will fit the width of the paragraph (or div-box) I am reading to the screen in most cases.

However, in IE on WP7 it doesn't do it and I have to scroll sideways all the time which is very annoying.

Am I missing something? Some gesture perhaps?

This is a huge annoyance in an otherwise pleasant mobile phone experience.

Comment: If possible, Please add a link to a page that doesn't resize well for you in IE.

Comment: Ok, I just surfed to the website http://www.everything2.org and if I zoom so far that I only see let's say 15 rows of text of the first black paragraph, I have to scroll left and right to read the full line. It should break the text so that I only have to scroll vertically. (See what happens if you zoom in the Firefox browser on the desktop.)

Comment: I see what you mean now. You can't zoom like that, double-tapping the screen is the only re-flow it will perform.

Comment: row1: Thank you. It's a pity though. I hope Microsoft adds this feature to the browser in the future. I do like the WP7 as a whole, but details like this kind of prevent me to recommend the OS to other people.

Answer (score 3):

To zoom until paragraph size I double tap that paragraph. IE always zoom to fit that paragraph in this way. I like this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It works quite well for me on most non-mobile pages. When you first open a page it will sometimes be slightly zoomed out, but if you double-tap the screen it will do its best to show the main content with no horizontal scroll and at a readable size.